# Java Producer/Consumer Concurrency Issue - NoSuchElementFound Exception while trying to read objects

Tags: java, concurrency, linked-list, synchronized, producer-consumer

We have this implementation of producer consumer.
Occassionally we get NoSuchElementException in the readRecord() method.
Ideally this should not happen as there is an if statement, and the method is synchronzied which makes sure that only one thread gets executed at any point in time. 
But still we get NoSuchElementException. Can somebody please guide me one this?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Listner{
    private LinkedList<Object> objList = new LinkedList<Object>();
    private Object listLock = new Object();

    public void writeRecord(Object obj){
        synchronized(listLock) {
            objList.add(obj);
        }
    }


    public synchronized Object readRecord(){
        Object obj = null;
        if( !objList.isEmpty() )
            obj = objList.removeFirst();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are locking on different object for `writeRecord` and `readRecord`?

Comment: First of all, I am not the author of this code. All I am trying to do is troubleshoot an issue with this implementation. And that's what I've described it as question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `readRecord` is synchronized, so there can be at most one `readRecord` at a time, but there is nothing preventing a `readRecord` and `writeRecord` running concurrently because they are locking on different objects. If it so happens that `writeRecord` is in the middle of adding a record so `isEmpty` returns false, but `removeFirst` cannot find the element because `writeRecord` hasn't finished adding it, you'd get that exception.

Synchronize on `listLock` in `readRecord`, or get rid of `listLock` and declare both methods as synchronized to fix it.

Comment: Serder Thanks that answers the question. One more followup. Can this be reproduced by writing unit tests??

Comment: You have to run two threads. More would be meaningless as readers and writers are synchronized among themselves. It'll be random. Start with an empty list with one writer one reader in separate threads to increase likelihood of failure.

Comment: *"Can this be reproduced by writing unit tests??"* - You cannot guarantee to reproduce it.   Concurrency / synchronization bugs are like that.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that.